# how to write php function inside javascript function

Tags: php, javascript

i want to call a php function **header('Location:http://xx.yy.zz/somthing')** inside a javascript function,Like given below.

```
<?php
<script>
function mUp(obj)
 {
 //here i want call the header function
 }
</scipt>
//some code
?>
```

Pls help..

Comment: You can not call a specific function from PHP with javascript. You could use AJAX to fetch a page that calls the function though.

Comment: That's not how you would use the `header()` function.

Comment: To be honest I'd suggest back tracking a little to learn the differences between js & php before continuing coding whatever you're coding

Comment: Take a few more mintutes and see if you can find a better [pattern](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-designptrns/)

Comment: I want the php function because i want the session variables to be available there.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not how it works.

Use:

```
window.location = "http://xx.yy.zz/somthing";
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi the following link may help you

http://forums.devarticles.com/javascript-development-22/calling-php-functions-with-javascript-3471.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute a PHP header function inside Javascript.

Javascript runs inside the browser, While PHP runs on  your server.

do something like

`window.location.href = "http://xx.yy.zz/somthing";`

Answer (score 0):

This is something for JavaScript, not for PHP:

```
<script>
function mUp(obj)
{
    document.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do a redirect, it would be good to redirect through javascript itself , if you want to write PHP code inside, just use PHP tags in between and write the code..or echo the javascript code and write PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

The code similar to PHP's `header()` `location` function:

```
header('Location:http://xx.yy.zz/somthing');
```

In javascript is,

```
location.href = "http://xx.yy.zz/somthing";
```

Both does the same redirect for the users, but the former one returns a HTTP Status of 301.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use directly the javascript version?

Have a look to [window.location](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp) object.

Answer (score 0):

why PHP function for redirecting ?
If you want to redirect simply

```
document.location.href='http://xx.yy.zz/somthing';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to put php code. .Just try this...

```
<script>
function mUp(obj)
{
 window.location="http://xx.yy.zz/somthing";
}
</scipt>
```

Answer (score 0):

By now you probably have noticed that If you put a php header redirect in after already sending html/any text to the client's browser, you get an error;
this is because the header() function tells the server to cancel the output from the current page and redirect to another page at the server-side.
so either you should find a way to execute that header function before printing any html/js to the broswer, or you could do a javascript redirect:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
   window.location.href="http://xx.yy.zz/somthing";
</script>
```

please comment if this isn't clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
header('Location:yourpage.php');
```